# React Javascript, form/ input validation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I am several inputs and checkboxes that all need to contain a value for the submit button to be enabled. Also, the value they enter for the name must not exist so I check it in an array using includes, I also tried checking it using regex and that doesn't work either. For the regex, it just doesn't work at all. For the includes method it works but the way my inputs are set up they are handled by onChange events when changed they update a state variable and call a function that checks if they are empty, already exist or within a specific range I set for the number input. So if I want to type PHP and I type first letter p it runs the includes a method to check if "p" exists and it finds a p and says yep I found a "p" it's true but that's not what I want, I want to check if the whole word exists in the array.

This is the regex I made up that doesn't seem to work.

```
let regex:RegExp = new RegExp(state_course_name, 'i');
        for(let i in technologies){
            console.log(technologies[i].name.match(regex));
               if(!!technologies[i].name.match(regex)){
                    return;
               }
        }
```

this is my function that checks the inputs every time there is a change that doesn't work that great.

```
const checkFormInput = ():boolean => {
        state_form_Validation = true;
        let mybool:boolean;
        if(state_tech_name !== "" && state_tech_description !== "" && state_tech_courseArray.length > 0 && state_tech_difficulty > 0 && state_tech_difficulty < 6){
            for(let i in technologies){
                mybool = technologies[i].name.includes(state_tech_name);
                //console.log(state_course_name);
                if(technologies[i].name.includes(state_course_name)){
                    state_form_Validation = false; 
                }
                //console.log(mybool);
            }
        } else {
            state_form_Validation = true;
        }
        setState_form_validation(state_form_Validation)
        return state_form_Validation;
    };
```

here are examples of an input and onchange handler

```
<input name="editTechs" type="submit" disabled={!state_form_Validation} onClick={() => {submitAdd();history.push("/");}} 
                        value="Add"/>

const add_tech_name = (e:any):void => {
        setState_tech_name(e.target.value);
        checkFormInput();
    };
```

Any help in making this work properly would be great, thanks in advance!